# How to create test data for automating acceptance test?

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration, agile, webdriver, acceptance-testing

I'm working on a legacy banking web application which uses oracle database with lots of stored procedures.

I have to write automated acceptance test suite for this application. 
Most of the acceptance tests requires a customer information to be entered in the system, which then perform some business rules and changes the customer's credit ratings.

The problem is that the information that is entered goes into the database which fires a sequence of stored procedures.

I want to know how to go about creating the test data for this application for my automation suite to run?

At this moment I have a few things in my mind:

- To create a separate database sandbox to run my acceptance test, but I'm worried that because of the stored procedures, would the replication be possible?
- Identify the tables and mock the dao's to return the test data which calls these tables?

As this seems to be a common scenario's for applications which need their acceptance test to be automated, I would like to know what approach is followed in projects which have similar cases.

The tech stack of web application is:
Spring 3.1, Hibernate and Java 6

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely MUST create a separate database sandbox. It's the only way to be sure of the state of your application when you're testing it. The creation of this sandbox DB should be part of your build process and should be fully scripted.

Have a look here for a more in-depth guide http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Database-Changes-Done-Right.aspx